# Actionscript button linking issue

Tags: actionscript-3, linker

So this doesn't make any sense.  I have actionscript in a flash-based button menu, and one of the buttons is linking to the wrong page, and i cannot figure out why.  Here is the actionscript:

```
var myURL1:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("home.html");
home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, home_btnEventHandler);
function home_btnEventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(myURL1, "_self");
}
var myURL2:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("featuredwork.html");
work_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, work_btnEventHandler);
function work_btnEventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(myURL2, "_self");
}
var myURL3:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("featuredartist.html");.
artist_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, artist_btnEventHandler);
function artist_btnEventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(myURL3, "_self");
}
var myURL4:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("artists.html");
members_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, members_btnEventHandler);
function members_btnEventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(myURL4, "_self");
}
var myURL5:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("events.html");
events_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, events_btnEventHandler);
function events_btnEventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(myURL5, "_self");
}
var myURL6:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("/blog/index.php");
blog_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, events_btnEventHandler);
function blog_btnEventHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(myURL6, "_self");
}
```

Now, when I click on blog_btn, it is sending me to the "events" page.  It makes no sense.  Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Please remove the extra line breaks and put four spaces before each line of code so we can read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly easy to spot: you have

```
blog_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, events_btnEventHandler);
```

when you mean

```
blog_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, blog_btnEventHandler);
```

notice the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You've bound the events handler to the `blog_btn` click - change the last block to point to the correct handler:

```
blog_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, blog_btnEventHandler);
```